# Phaser inputEnabled Sprite has mouseover even if not on stage

Tags: sprite, phaser-framework

I found that if I add a Sprite (with inputEnabled = true) to a group and don't add the group to the stage, I can still interact with the Sprite (although it's not shown).

```
var group = App.phaser.add.group(null, null, false, false);
var bmd = App.phaser.add.bitmapData(100, 100);
bmd.ctx.beginPath();
bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#ff9900';
bmd.ctx.fill();
var sprite = App.phaser.add.sprite(0, 0, bmd);

group.addChild(sprite);
// group.visible = false;

sprite.x = 100;
sprite.y = 100;
sprite.inputEnabled = true;
sprite.input.useHandCursor = true;
```

The stage is completely blank (which is good). But when I move my mouse over the top left corner I see a mousecursor (and any added event handlers would also respond).
Only way to prevent this form happening is to set the group's visibility to false, but this is clearly not the best solution.
I'm doing somthing wrong or this is a bug in Phaser?

Answer (score 1):

Sprites don't have to be on the display list in order to be interactive, they just have to have 'inputEnabled' set on them. This is commonly used to allow you to create 'invisible' hit areas.

If you want the sprite to be ignored for input you can call `sprite.input.stop()` and toggle it back on as needed with `start`.

Also please use `Group.add` otherwise the sprite doesn't get assigned a z value, throwing it out of sequence in the Group.

Comment: In my opinion it would make more sens to attach it and just set the alpha to 0 (how else would the sprite know what it's a hitarea from?).
Anyway it still feels like a bug since in this case I can't use it that way because the hit area remains in the top left corner (even if the x and y of either sprite or group are set to some other values). Also why does this only happen when it's attached to a group and not when it's not attached to anything?

Comment: ..also having to stop the input is a bit tricky since either the group should keep track of the input of it's children or the child should keep track of the visibility of it's parent. Surely this is possible but it would make the code unnecessary complex and is just begging for bugs.

Comment: Visibility has nothing to do with if it can be used for input or not, so it makes no difference if the child knows about the visibility of its parent (which it does anyway), or if the Group knows about the input state of it children (which it doesn't, because it's irrelevant from the Groups point of view).

If you think this is a bug then it's being reported in the wrong place.

Comment: Just not sure if it's a bug or some construction I don't get / am not used to. Anyway I'll manage for now, hopefully I'll find some time later to dive into this issue a bit deeper.